# Way to find the size of LinkedList without iterating through entire List

Tags: java, linked-list

Is there a way to find the size/length of singly LinkedList without iterating through entire list. The List is already populated so there is no option of maintaining a counter and increment it each time an element is added.

Comment: Are you asking about one of the collections' linked lists or linked lists in general ?

Comment: No. That would internally use the same method I think?

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock abstract concept

Comment: For clarification on the flow of comments - I had asked whether ghostrider was asking about specifically Java's java.util.LinkedList or an abstract concept.  I saw it as the same as Gautam's question and deleted the original comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Unless you have some auxiliary data in the list's implementation (like a counter that's incremented each time an element is added, as you suggested), you have no choice but to iterate over the entire list and count the elements.